# PHP intentando añadir un valor con una key en una array ya existente

Tags: php, array, php7

Tengo este array :

```
$datos = array(
        'titulo' => $titulo, 
        'contenido' => $contenido, 
        'usuario' => $usuario
    );
```

Y quiero añadir un **nuevo elemento** pero no solo el **valor** si no una **key** para poder identificarlo, tal cual estan en el **array** `$datos` que ya tengo creado.

Por tanto intento esto :

```
array_push($datos, 'url_img' =>$fileNameNew);
```

pero me dice basicamente que **no puede tener una key**, pero me interesaria guardarlo con su key pues para tratarlo mas adelante en ciertas **funciones**

Comment: asi -> `$datos['url_img'] = $fileNameNew`

Comment: Muchas gracias !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Donde yo se no existe una función para añadir al `array` una nueva clave y valor.

Así que he creado uno:

```
function addKeyAndValue( &$array, $key, $value ) {

    $array[$key] = $value;
}
```

<kbd>**[Ver Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/da98d8505e84bc454665b917e5056d7f3c58198d)**</kbd>

[+ Info](https://php.net/manual/es/language.references.pass.php) sobre `&` (Pasar por referencia)

Comment: Muchas gracias @BlackSheep , el de tu comentario me valio perfectamente !!

Comment: De nada hombre... un saludo